# showing selection for buttons on UIToolbar

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitoolbar

I have 4 buttons on uitoolbar and I have images for all four button for default state only.
On selection, I need to show it as selected. Now my question is that how to show button as selected when there is no image for selected state. I want to show the button as mentioned in following image. How to do it.[image]

Comment: Use a tab bar. What you have shown is an image of [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and not a [UIToolbar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: @ACB: Thanks, but I cannot use  UITabBarController  for some reason.

Comment: @ACB: Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @RahulGupta for what reason? If there really is a reason, then why don't you use a simple `UITabBar` instead of the whole `UITabBarController`?

Comment: @H2CO3: Actually I have 10 to 12 buttons at bottom, so I have added all buttons in scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for the flag: "forState". I would appear like this:

```
forState:UIControlStateNormal
```

when your tab is being selected, you should change the state to "UIControlStateSelected".

Comment: I have done this, but its not looking as selected as shown in image.